# JAVA: Why images is loaded slower than the app, Window Frame?

Tags: java, image, canvas, bufferedimage

I'm using an image to draw a background for a Java app, a big one without repeat property. To do so, I used bufferedImage to read the resource, the image, and draw it in a Canvas. Well, it works almost fine. Except one thing, the app still opens even though the image are fallen behind.

I mean, I expected to see both the app and image were loaded at the same time. But it seems like the image has only been loaded after the app started, long enough to see the window frame background (gray color cause I'm using Windows 10).

So I tried my solution by `setVisible(true);` after the Canvas class has been initialized. The result is still the same.

One more exception that I don't know if it's relevant to the image. But after I closed the app, the console has thrown out an exception called 'Closed'. It like after I close my app, there is still a part of my coding running and try to read the image.

Here are my code:

App.class (main class in here)

```
import engine.MouseAction;
import graphic.Game;
import graphic.Window;

public class App {
    MouseAction mouse;
    Game game;
    Window window;

    App() {
        init();
        setup();
        window.launch();//It's just window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        mouse = new MouseAction();

        game = new Game();
        window = new Window(game, mouse);
    }

    private void setup() {
        mouse.setWindow(window);
        game.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

Game.class

```
package graphic;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import engine.Config;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -545327428912119369L;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game() {}

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void update() {

    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING , RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        try {
            BufferedImage bg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/assets/img/bg.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, Config.SOL_16x10_small.width, Config.SOL_16x10_small.height, this);
            bg.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTick = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTick; //It's nano second
        double delta = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
        }

        stop();
    }

}
```

That is 2 classes I think it's relevant to my problem. And this code does load images but it loads very slow.

Comment: It looks like you're loading the image in the `render()` method.  This takes time.  You should load the image first (into memory) and then show the window with the image.

Comment: You'll also find that until the whole node is realised on the screen, you can't create a BufferedStrategy. I'd also agree with Steve, I'd recommend loading the images you need ahead of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your gameloop. You try to load your image file into memory on every iteration of your gameloop, just before you get your graphics context to actually draw it.

Try to load the image into memory beforehand, then simply call the drawing method of Graphics g to render it on every iteration.

You could load the image anywhere before you start your gameloop.

You could also create the bufferstrategy beforehand and then simply get the graphics context in your render() method, the way you do it already.

Ultimately saving the if(bs == null), this will not make any noticeable difference though.